# Can't make a boot disk

Tags: boot, mac, disk

...For the newest version of Ubuntu.

Am using a Macbook, have tried both USB and CD instructions down to a T with no luck.
On my mac, with both the cd and USB I get the error 'failed to read media' or something to that effect. I've gone through about 20 discs and it's driving me insane.

On my computer with no OS, if I try to boot with the USB I get the error 'Isolinux.bin is missing or corrupt'

So...Er, possibilities of what is going wrong? I'd prefer the USB because it's reusable and because my optical drive for my new computer has been lost in the post (but that's a completely different grizzle altogether).

I have also sifted through youtube and google and tried just about every slight little variation on the instructions and none of that has worked either.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it might be wise for you to download/re-download (just to make sure) the [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download) distribution again. If you do so, depending on your Mac Book specifications you either choose 32bit or 64bit! Actually it might be, that you choose the wrong architecture in the first place!!!

After downloading either **ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso** or **ubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.iso** you open up `terminal.app` and use this command to burn the image. `hdiutil burn Imagename.iso`

Make sure you replace `Imagename.iso` with your path and imagename, like so:
**hdiutil burn ~/Desktop/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso**

You could also burn your Ubuntu-image with either **DiskUtility.app** or **Toast.app**

If you now restart you Mac with the new image-cd inserted, you can hold down the `alt`key after the chime and choose "cd-option"!